# Inserting an image into "Geany" compiler

Tags: python

so I am coding in python and am using pygame in my compiler by the name of "Geany". I am trying to add an image to my project as a png file so I can display it but I couldnt seem to find a way to do it. Let me know if you can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the pygame documentation on how to insert and display images.

The syntax of the function :

```python
var = pygame.image.load('var.png').convert()
```

You can either create a game object, or just display it.

To turn it into an game object:

```python
o = GameObject(player, y, x)
```

Use the above code provided, and please read the pygame documentation on more information about this.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I fixed the issue. I think I also worded my question incorrectly.